# Why is not $\,f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)$ a one to one function?

Tags: analysis, functions, trigonometry, continuity, inverse-function

> Why is not $\,f(x)=\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)$ a one to one function?

I've always knew inverse trig functions to be one to one on a specific range. But from the graph of the above inverse trig function it shows that it’s not one to one. My question is why? Also what are the necessary restrictions for the function to act as one to one?

Comment: The trig function is irrelevant. The function $f(x)=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not one-to-one on $[0,1]$. Indeed, $f(0)=f(1)=0$ at the endpoints but $f(x)>0$ within the interval, which is itself enough to see why $f$ cannot be one-to-one (and thus $\sin^{-1}f$ can't be either, even though $\sin^{-1}$ is).

Comment: $x\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$ at both $0$ and $1$

Comment: Your formula *is* not a function, but may be used to define one. You need to specify the domain and target you want to consider.  If the domain is chosen small enough it sure defines an injective function (which I assume you mean by one-to-one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Note the function $y=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not one to one, as shown in the figure. And you can rigorously prove this fact by using the intermediate value theorem and continuity (try it). So the function $f(x)=\arcsin(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$ is not one to one.

Answer (score 3):

As noticed the function $\arcsin x$ is one to one and also $\arcsin (f(x))$ is one to one when $f(x)$ is one to one, indeed

$$\arcsin (f(x_1))=\arcsin (f(x_2)) \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$$

but in this case $2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is not one to one in the domain of interest, indeed for example

$$2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}=0\iff x_{1,2}=0,1$$

which implies that the composition is not one to one since $\exists x_1$ and $\exists x_2$ such that

$$\arcsin (f(x_1))=\arcsin (f(x_2))$$

with $x_1\neq x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Although $\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$ is one-to-one on $\left[-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right]$, it is not one-to-one on $[-1,1]$ because $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not one-to-one on that interval. However, $\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=2\arcsin(x)$ when $x^2\le\frac12$, and $2\arcsin(x)$ is one-to-one on $[-1,1]$.

[image]

Furthermore, for $x^2\ge\frac12$
$$
\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)+2\arcsin(x)=\pi\operatorname{sgn}(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(g(x))$ requires $g(x)$ to be injective and $f(x)$ to be injective to be injective.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is not injective, so it doesn't have an inverse which maps its range to the entirety of its domain. However, $\arcsin(x)$ *is* a monotonically increasing function, taking $[-1,1]$ to $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: @robjohn $\arcsin: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ isn't a function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#definition

Comment: $\arcsin:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ *is* a function. Just because the domain is not $\mathbb{R}$ does not prevent it from being a function.

Comment: We agree with each other